# Unexpected token, expected , in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind, babeljs

I have a React component that looks like this

```
'use strict';

import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import TreeNode from './TreeView';

export default React.createClass({

  mapFromApi : function(data)  {
    const rec = (tree) => tree.reduce((x,y) => {

      const newObj = {
        "id" : y["@id"],
        "name" : y["rdfs:label"]
      };

      if (y.hasOwnProperty("options")) {
        newObj.children = rec(y.options, []);
      }
      if (y.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
        newObj.children = rec(y.children, []);
      }

      x.push(newObj);
      return x;
    }, []);

    let t = rec(data);

    return t;

  },
  render: function (data) {
    let tree1 = this.mapFromApi(this.props.data.properties).map(child => {
        return <TreeNode key={child['id']} data={child}/>;
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div className='vocab'>
      <h4>vocab1</h4>
        <div className='accordion'>
            {tree1}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

When I run this I get an error on the bind keyword

```
SyntaxError: App.jsx: Unexpected token, expected , (56:5)
  54 |     let tree1 = this.mapFromApi(this.props.data.properties).map(child => {
  55 |         return <TreeNode key={child['id']} data={child}/>;
> 56 |     }.bind(this));
     |      ^
  57 |
  58 |     return (
  59 |       <div className='vocab'>
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with my Babel setup and I'm very confused about the whole es version situation.

Can some one help me resolve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simplify the way this code is laid out, these kind of syntax errors should be easier to identify.

```
let { data } = this.props;

this
  .mapFromApi(data.properties)
  .map(child => <TreeNode key={child.id} data={child} />)
```

The arrow function is already going to `.bind(this)` for you, so you can just omit that.

Comment: Thanks I realised this after I read your article on the matter. [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use .bind(this) because you are using the ES6 `arrow` function `=>` and that will reference the correct `this`

I would write some thing like this

```
const {data} = this.props;

let tree1 = this.mapFromApi(data.properties).map(child => {
    return <TreeNode key={child['id']} data={child}/>;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well.  After reading Dan's article I understood bind a little more.  This is how my code looks right now.  I didn't have to bind due to the arrow function.